# Use CSS to show table rows as colums

Tags: html, css

I want label and value to align correctly according to the longest label size by using a table. For large screen sizes I want to show sets of 2 table rows as columns (like in fig B). Is there a CSS only way to achieve such an responsive display change?

[sandbox](https://codepen.io/wong3000/pen/rNjVgjr)

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="cell">label 1</div>
   <div class="cell">value 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell"> looooooooooong label 2</div>
  <div class="cell">value 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">label 3</div>
  <div class="cell">value 3</div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">label 4</div>
  <div class="cell">value 4</div>
</div>  
</div>
```

[image: The responsive states of the table:]

Comment: Probably want to use something like grid and media queries

Comment: @Pete css grid to break the table?

Comment: not sure what you mean by break but you can change the layout of your divs

Comment: alternative `flexbox` with `flex-direction` can do the same thing as CSS-Grid.

Comment: @tacoshy Problem with flex box and the order of the boxes is that you would probably need a fixed height

Comment: @tacoshy but with flexbox the alignment of lable and value are not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an improvement of the solution started by @Fakt309. I used `flex-order` (order) to re-arrange the items for large screens.

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 801px) {
    .row:nth-of-type(1) {
      order: 1;
    }
      
    .row:nth-of-type(2) {
      order: 3;
    }
      
    .row:nth-of-type(3) {
      order: 2;
    }
      
    .row:nth-of-type(4) {
      order: 4;
    }
}
```

Also I added `flex-direction: column;` for smalls creens to have the items then aligned below each other.

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}
.cell {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  word-break: break-all;
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 800px) {
    .table {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .row {
      width: 90%;
    }
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 801px) {
    .row:nth-of-type(1) {
      order: 1;
    }
  
    .row:nth-of-type(2) {
      order: 3;
    }
  
    .row:nth-of-type(3) {
      order: 2;
    }
  
    .row:nth-of-type(4) {
      order: 4;
    }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<div class="table">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="cell">label 1</div>
   <div class="cell">value 1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell"> looooooooooong label 2</div>
  <div class="cell">value 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">label 3</div>
  <div class="cell">value 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">label 4</div>
  <div class="cell">value 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
}

.cell {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  word-break: break-all;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .row {
    width: 90%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">label 1</div>
    <div class="cell">value 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> looooooooooong label 2</div>
    <div class="cell">value 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">label 3</div>
    <div class="cell">value 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">label 4</div>
    <div class="cell">value 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: interessting, but the text is not correctly aligned. I would like the result to look like Fig. b)

Comment: Changed Changed Changed

Comment: but value 2 and value 4 are not aligned

Comment: still the same. Value 2 should come below value 1 not right of it. Use `flex-order` to re-arrange